# Form field alignment difficulty in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my form, I have an '`Add number`' button that adds `text input` fields inside the `div` for 'Phone' using `jquery`. But as I add new field for input, it does not keep in line with the other field. Currently it has the following output:

[image: Current output is like this:]

But I want the input fields for the phone number more organized. Like the following image and the `Remove` button at the right side of the input fields.
[image: That I need]

I am not sure how to do this with bootstrap. Here is a sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashonko/nuawj8dh/) of the code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
        var count = 0;

        $('p#add_field').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                '<div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
            );
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>  
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control input-md" type="text">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <div id="container" class="input_fields_wrap">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="dose">Phone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10"> 
              <p id="add_field"><button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span>Add number</span></button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: without looking at code, i'd say you need to set each li or div with col-xs-1 col-xs-(whatever) to line them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to put the added fields in their own bootstrap columns including an empty one at the beginning.  Or you could just use the `col-sm-offet-2` class.

```
<div class="col-sm-2"></div>
<div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"/></div>
<div class="col-sm-1"><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nuawj8dh/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but it creates a new problem that the `remove` link now doesn't work.

Comment: OK, try this one instead `<div><div class="col-sm-2"></div><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"/></div><a href="#" class="remove_field col-sm-1">Remove</a></div>`

Comment: Wow! It's now perfect. Thanks for your effort.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Think this is what you are looking for:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
   <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <label class="control-label">Name</label> 
      </div> 
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control input-md" type="text">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <div id="container" class="input_fields_wrap">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label class="control-label" for="dose">Phone</label>
         </div>
          <div class="col-sm-10"> 
              <p id="add_field"><button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span>Add number</span></button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>

   </form>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var count = 0;

    $('p#add_field').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        count += 1;
        $('#container').append(
            '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-2"></div><div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"/></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
        );
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    })
});
```

A problem you are having is that you put the class `col-sm-2` for the label. This will not render correctly from my experience, always safer to have that class in the div. This will always improve the responsiveness of your site.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but though it solves the design, it creates a new problem that the `remove` link now doesn't work now. Any suggestion why or how can it be solved?

Comment: Ive updated my answer, changed the JS code, try this now.

Answer (score 0):

Give the newly generated `div`s a bootstrap class, say, going by your code, `col-sm-10`.

```
$('#container').append(
            '<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
        );
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap");
        var count = 0;

        $('p#add_field').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count += 1;
            $('#container').append(
                '<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="field_' + count + '" name="fields[]' + '"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
            );
        });

        $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('div').remove();
            x--;
        })
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <form class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>  
         <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input class="form-control input-md" type="text">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <div id="container" class="input_fields_wrap">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="dose">Phone</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10"> 
              <p id="add_field"><button type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-info"><span>Add number</span></button></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      
   </form>
</div>
```